# How to get a timeline of posts of only people someone follows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do something like Instagram where you can see images of people you only follow. A user can follow another user and create new posts.

This is what i have for following and unfollowing in my Users controller.

```
def following
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  current_user.mark_as_following @user

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to @user}
    format.js
  end
end

def unfollow
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.unmark :following, :by => current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to @user}
    format.js
  end
end
```

Here is my my Posts controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   load_and_authorize_resource 
   def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end

   def new
      @post = Post.new
   end

   def create
       @post.user_id = current_user.id
       if @post.save
          redirect_to @post
       else
          render :new
       end
   end

   def edit
       @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end

   def update
       @post = Post.find(params[:id])
       if @post.update_attributes(update_params)
           redirect_to @post
       else
           render :edit
       end
   end

   private
       def update_params
           params.require(:post).permit(:caption, :image)
       end

       def create_params
           params.require(:post).permit(:caption, :user_id, :image)
       end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a controller like this

```
class FollowingPostsController < ApplicationController

   def index
      @posts = current_user.following_posts
   end
end
```

and in your User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def following_posts
      #assuming that following_users returns the list of following users
      self.following_users.map{ |user| user.posts }.flatten(1)
  end
end
```

Or you can get the list of posts with :

```
Post.where(user_id: self.following_users.ids)
```

Comment: You can use a join to get the posts in one query. What you suggest here will result in a query for every user you follow.

Comment: but the join will return a list of users not a list of posts

Comment: You have to start with `Post` and then join in the user tables you need. I don't know his model/attribute names, but something like: `Post.joins(:user, :user_followings).where(:follower_id => current_user.id)`. This will return the posts you need in one query.

Comment: how to get current_user post also be generated in timeline? do we have to make sure that we follow ourselves first?

Comment: Post.where(user_id: self.following_users.ids<<self.id)